# How to detect that a button is clicked inside a JFrame in java

Tags: java, button, jframe, listener

I'm working on a little game in Java and I have a class that is extended JFrame and that is the interface of my game. I have an other class that instantiate my First class and it needs to when a button is clicked and which one. How do I do that?

Comment: What have you already tried before coming here?

Comment: I know how to had a actionListener, but I would need a way that would allow my second class to notice that a button was click and which one, like dispatching an event for exemple.

Comment: You'll need to specify some more, and maybe provide some code. I'm not exactly sure what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out EventListeners. They may help you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how you can detect the click inside a [**JFrame**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html):

```
myJFrame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Clickin' =)");
   }
});
```